# Calling a ContentProvider custom method with multiple arguments using adb

Tags: android, adb, android-contentprovider

In an app I am debugging, In a content provider that's `exported=true`, I have the following method:

```
public int myMethod(Uri uri, String name) { 
    return name.length;
}
```

I would like to test it via ADB. I'm not sure how to call it properly with the arguments.

`adb shell content call --uri content://my_provider_url/ --method myMethod --arg Hello --arg2 Adam`

I've also tried:

`adb shell content call --uri content://my_provider_url/ --extra "URI:s:Hello" --extra "NAME:s:Adam"`

Didn't work either - I keep getting `Result:Null`

I wish I could just add bindings - but the code isn't mine. How can I test this provider properly using adb (or a similar tool)?

Comment: What you passing two args to a method that takes one string? Maybe omit `--arg2 Adam`.

Comment: @dominicoder I get Result: null

Comment: @Robert You're right - it returns the name length. Fixed.

Comment: To my understanding the `content call --method` only allows one string argument. If you want to call it via adb you may need to develop your custom version of `content` which is actually a Java application: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/cmds/content/src/com/android/commands/content/Content.java